# Efficient method of approximating a distribution with Gaussian

Tags: approximation, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation, monte-carlo

Given a univariate uni-modal density function $f(x)$ (very hard to compute its cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F(x)$, not to mention its inverse CDF $F^{-1}(x)$),

how to find the best Gaussian/normal approximation without drawing samples from the density function $f(x)$ via rejection method and then computing the mean and variance?

Comment: Best approximation in what sense?

Comment: @RobertIsrael minimize KL-divergence

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for rejection – you can estimate the mean and variance by numerical quadrature. That only requires some function evaluations; if even that is too expensive, I don't see what you could possibly do, since you'd essentially have a mystery function in a black box that you can't know anything about.